# How to pass any enum that conforms to protocols to SwiftUI view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have 3+ enums that all conform to `CaseIterable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible`. I would like to pass these enums to a SwiftUI Picker. Seeing as the code would be the same for all the enums I want to just pass the enum to a custom view I've made. I'm just not sure how to pass the enums in a generic way.

Here's the code I've tried. It obviously won't compile as is.

```
struct EnumPickerView: View {
    var title: String
    var listItems: CaseIterable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible
    @Binding var pickedValue: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(title, selection: $pickedValue)  {
            ForEach(any CaseIterable.allCases) {
                Text($0.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should get acquainted with the basics first, before trying to go for generics. There are many errors in your code: 1) You need to define a generic type at the struct, like `struct EnumPickerView<T: CaseIterable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible>: View`; 2) the variable type is a generic, `var listItems: T`; 3) The ForEach requires a variable, not a type, like`ForEach(listItem, id: \.self) { item in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a generic implementation like this:

```
struct EnumPickerView<T: CaseIterable & Identifiable & Hashable & CustomStringConvertible>: View {
    
    var title: String
    @Binding var pickedValue: T
    
    var body: some View {
        Picker(title, selection: $pickedValue)  {
            ForEach(Array(T.allCases)) { option in
                Text(option.description).tag(option)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that T defines the enum type, hence you can use `allCases` on it.
The `tag` allows a proper selection.
And you can use it like this:

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible, Identifiable {
    
    case option1
    case option2
    case option3
    
    // Identifiable
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
    
    // CustomStringConvertible
    var description: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    
    @State private var enumValue: MyEnum = .option1 // <-- defines values for picker, and keeps the currently selected value
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            EnumPickerView(title: "some title", pickedValue: $enumValue)
            Text(enumValue.description) // <-- just to display a picked value
        }
    }
    
}
```

`MyEnum` doesn't have to be String, but all the protocol requirements remain the same.

Comment: I knew it had to be a generic I just wasn't sure how to define it. Thank you.